# On including conserved charges when maximizing entropy of a statistical system

Tags: statistical-mechanics, conservation-laws, entropy

One approach towards constructing the probability of a state in a system is by maximizing the constrained entropy

$$
S[p(n);\alpha,\beta] = -\sum_np(n)\log(p(n))\;+\;
\alpha\big(\sum_nE_np(n) -\langle E\rangle\big)\;+\; \beta\big(\sum_np(n) - 1\big).
$$
However, if there is a continuous symmetry in my Hamiltonian that preserves a charge $Q$, why not include this
$$
S[p(n);\alpha,\beta,\gamma] = -\sum_np(n)\log(p(n))\;+\;
\alpha\big(\sum_nE_np(n) -\langle E\rangle\big)\;+\; \beta\big(\sum_np(n) - 1\big)
\\+\gamma\big(\sum_nq_np(n)+\langle Q\rangle \big)?
$$
Does it make sense to do something like this or is there something clearly wrong with it.

Perhaps this makes more sense in for a quantum statistical system. Since the conserved charge commutes with the Hamiltonian, there will be many eigenstates $|n\rangle$ with the same charge $q_i$ for some $i$. Therefore, performing the sum in the second equation might make more sense.